What is the benefit of transfering oxalic acid to a volumetric flask via a glass funnel?
I am going over the lab instructions for a chemistry experiment for a titration. This part of the instructions are for making oxalic acid from crystalline oxalic acid:

Transfer exact weight of crystalline oxalic acid to a glass funnel placed above a 100 ml volumetric flask. Give a fine spray of distilled water from the  wash bottle to bring everything down to the volumetric flask. Shake everything....

If the objective is to transfer the oxalic acid to the volumetric flask is there any benefit to doing it via the glass funnel? What if it is directly transferred to the volumetric flask?
Edit: I forget to mention that the oxalic acid is orginally in crystalline form (mentioned earlier on in the same instructions).If it were liquid, I could understand risk of spillage, etc.

These instructions have been arrived at by watching generations of students spill oxalic acid on the bench when trying to transfer it to the flask.

How does directly mean not quantitatively and via the funnel mean quantitively?

-1 You can lose some of powder just as well as liquid, it should be obvious.

Transfering weighted solids directly to volumetric flasks without funnels is at risk of not doing so quantitatively. Otherwise, funnels would not be invented.

How does directly mean not quantitatively and via the funnel mean quantitatively?

It does not.
Probability of spilling is dependent on the diameter. It does not mean you would spill without a funnel but would not with it. Using funnels is spilling precaution. Generally. Based on experience of many chemists over almost 200 years.
Being solid increases the risk of spillage, which involves both accidental falling of solid particles and splashing while transferring solids to a flask.
Transfering liquids offers safer ways, e.g. using pipettes.

Complementary to the accepted answer by @Poutnik, a second question can be: Other than the glass funnel, what would be the alternatives for the transfer of solids into a volumetric flask?

weighing paper. Not so much suitable for samples which are oily, or somewhat not dry (not only in terms of presence/absence of water). Sometimes electrostatics in dry air (not only in glove boxes) can be an issue, too. You have to fold and unfold the square prior to weighting (and account for its weight) and bend the thing a little bit like a funnel to fit into the mouth of the flask without loosing some of the material. Cheap in material, but obviously usage requires some dexterity. It can be a matter of training/personal training/specific situation if you prefer them over using watch glasses of varying diameters.

image credit Whatmann/Sigma Aldrich

weighing boats and pans. Their rim provides rigidity, but typically this equally can hinder the transfer of solid product into a volumetric flask. Because they are made of aluminum, or plastic, a rinse with water to complete the transfer wouldn't be a problem if the rim were equally suitable.  In some labs (not only teaching labs) they tend to disappear despite purchase costs more.

(credit Sigma-Aldrich)

(credit Sigma-Aldrich)

weighing scoops/weighing shoes. They can be very nice as the pan to weigh and the funnel to easily transfer the material - including a rinse to complete the transfer - is one piece only. The more affordable ones are made of plastic, else of glass. Compared to the other equipment listed, it is an item more frequently seen in labs dedicated to analytical chemistry and quality control, than in others.

(credit Sigma)

(credit Sigma)


Compared to OP's question of

What if [oxalic acid] is directly transferred to the volumetric flask?

these

often weigh much lesser, than the (empty) volumetric flask to prepare the solution. Analytical balances with a reading down to $\pu{0.1 mg}$ (or less) are not suitable for heavy weights.
are small enough to fit into the enclosure of an analytical balance. Often, volumetric flasks are simply too tall to fit into this constrained space. Or/and to wide compared to the diameter of the pan of the balance. And if they fit, the open diameter of their mouth is so small that addition of material with a spatula into the flask would become a delicate task (you don't want to spill this place) / too time consuming (some samples are hygroscopic, even deliquescent, too - this would introduce an error to the analysis).

Each of these alternatives to "go to the shelf to pick just a plain small beaker (to weigh-in) and glass funnel of suitable size for the volumetric flask" has some disadvantage regarding prize of purchase, handling/reliable transfer of material in the hands of inexperienced users. On the other hand, funnels made of glass is a bulk commodity of known chemical resistivity, easy to use, clean, reuse and recycle.

those weighting scoops/shoes are nice. In the past, it was not so common to have ones integrated with their own funnel, so one had to use a funnel. // The paper can have an issue with quantitative transfer, for both soluble and insoluble solids.
